# Copying dicts from csv to a new dict-python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a parser that reads from a text file and returns dicts like this:

```
{'m/z array': array([  345.1,   370.2,   460.2,  1673.3,  1674. ,  1675.3]),
'charge array': array([ 3,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1]),
'params': {'username': 'Lou Scene', 'useremail': 'leu@altered-state.edu',
'mods': 'Carbamidomethyl (C)', 'itolu': 'Da', 'title': 'Spectrum 2',
'rtinseconds': '25', 'itol': '1', 'charge':`enter code here` '2+ and 3+',
'mass': 'Monoisotopic', 'it_mods': 'Oxidation (M)',
'pepmass': (1084.9, 1234.0),
'com': 'Based on http://www.matrixscience.com/help/data_file_help.html',
'scans': '3'},
'intensity array': array([  237.,   128.,   108.,  1007.,   974.,    79.])}
```

I am trying to read the entire file (all the dicts) and store them in an object for passing to a second function so the script doesn't have to read from the file every time (which is very slow). I would like to retain the original structure of the data while passing it around for ease of access. What is the best way to do this?

I tried using the following code:

```
print ('enter mgf file name')
mgf_file = str(raw_input())
from pyteomics import mgf
reader = []
with mgf.read(mgf_file) as temp_read:
    for things in temp_read:
        reader.update(things)


compo_reader(reader)
```

Comment: What parser are you using? What does the code to use it look like?

Comment: You still need to show us your code, rather than make us read the docs and try to guess what code you might have written with that library. Please see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more help on what makes a good question.

Comment: Sorry about that! I am new to this website and programming and still learning how to do this properly. i have edited my original post. Thanks for responding.

Comment: No problem—the reason the help section is there is that nobody could be expected to guess how to do everything perfectly on their first try. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put them in a list and pass the list around.

Since you didn't show us your code, I can't show you how to change it, but I can show you with some fake code.

Let's say you have a function `parser(f)` that reads one row from `f` and returns one of those dictionaries you showed us, or `None` when it's done. So:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    things = []
    while True:
        thing = parser(f)
        if not thing:
            break
        things.append(thing)
```

Or, more compactly:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    things = list(iter(partial(parser, f), None))
```

If you're using a parser which is already an iterable, like `csv.DictReader`, then it's even simpler:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    things = list(reader)
```

However you've done it, once you have a list of those dictionaries, you can pass that list around, iterate over it, etc.

---

For your specific code, it looks like an `mgf.read()` object is an iterator over dictionaries, just like a `csv.DictReader`, so it should be just:

```
with mgf.read(mgf_file) as temp_read:
    reader = list(temp_read)
```

If that weren't true, you'd want to do this:

```
reader = []
with mgf.read(mgf_file) as temp_read:
    for thing in temp_read:
        reader.append(thing)
```

In other words, instead of repeatedly calling `update` on a dict with each new dict, just `append` each one to a list.